# Remove Duplicates Data(Model name and price) from Arraylist and add model with Price(adding) in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have one Arraylist. In Arraylist there are two values Model name and Price. But there are many Duplicates Value.

```
First Arraylist : Samsung s duos - 10000(Price)
                  Samsung s duos - 10000
                  Redmi note 3 - 12000
                  Redmi note 3 - 12000
```

I want to data in another Arraylist like(Price Adding when same model name is found)

```
Second Arraylist:  Samsung s duos - 20000(price Adding)
                   Redmi Note 3 - 24000
```

Here is my code....

```
class Model {
    String NAME = "";
    String PRICE= "";
}

ArrayList<Model> dataone = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Here, this is AsyncTask(Background method), I put data one first arraylist...

```
while (result.next()) {
                Model dataa = new Model();
                dataa.NAME = result.getString(1);
                dataa.PRICE = result.getString(2);
                dataone.add(dataa);
            }
```

Here is my Full code....

```
public class ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise extends Activity{
  String type, name, toDate, frmDate, brandName;
  ArrayList<Model> datas;
  List<String> list_header;
  ArrayList<Model> dataone;
  ListView ll;
  Intent intent;
  SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profit_report_item_name_brand_wise);
    type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    Log.e("typ","----"+type);
    brandName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    Log.e("brand","----"+brandName);
    toDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("toDate");
    Log.e("todate","----"+toDate);
    frmDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("frmDate");
    Log.e("frmdate","----"+frmDate);
    list_header = new ArrayList<String>();
    datas = new ArrayList<Model>();
    dataone = new ArrayList<Model>();
    pref = getSharedPreferences(new Const().pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
    ll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    intent = new Intent(ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this,ProfitabilityReportFinal.class);
    new GetData().execute();
}


public class Model {

    String name;
    int price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            if (datas.size() > 0) {
                Adptor adptor = new Adptor(
                        ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this,
                        R.layout.textview_list, datas);
                ll.setAdapter(adptor);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this,
                        "No Data Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this,
                    "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection(
                    ProfitReportItemNameBrandWise.this);

            Query qtry = new Query();

            String query = qtry.createQuery(
                    qtry.query,
                    new String[] { "profitabilityreporttotalwithqty",
                            pref.getString("username", ""),
                            pref.getString("company", ""),
                            pref.getString("ProfitCenter", ""), frmDate,
                            toDate, brandName, "ALL" });

            ResultSet result = conn.getResultFromserver(query);

            while (result.next()) {
                Model dataa = new Model();
                dataa.name = result.getString(3);
                dataa.price = result.getInt(7);
                dataone.add(dataa);
            }
            conn.con.close();
            if (dataone .size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataone.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataone.size(); j++) {
                        if (dataone.get(i).getName().equals(dataone.get(j).getName())) {
                            if (datas.size() > 0) {
                                for (int k = 0; k < datas.size(); k++) {
                                    if (datas.get(k).getName().equals(dataone.get(j).getName())) {
                                        datas.get(k).setPrice(datas.get(k).getPrice() + dataone.get(j).getPrice());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                     datas.add(dataone.get(j));
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("error", "" + e);
            return false;
        }

    }

    private class Adptor extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public Adptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Model> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textviewsingle, null);
            }
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView profit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profit);
            ll.setTag(datas.get(position));
            name.setText(datas.get(position).name);
            profit.setText(datas.get(position).price);
            ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Model dats = (Model) v.getTag();

                    intent.putExtra("name", dats.name);
                    intent.putExtra("brandName", brandName);
                    intent.putExtra("toDate", toDate);
                    intent.putExtra("frmDate", frmDate);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please Help me....Thanks

Comment: dataone is nothing but a first ArrayList?

Comment: Yes,dataone is first arraylist

Comment: you can achieve using set,Any specific requirement like to use ArrayList?

Comment: I am just new born in Android....Any Methos you use,but I want as Second arraylist as given my question...Thanks

Comment: @DharmikPatel please stop duplicating your questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522842/error-didt-retrive-data-from-arraylist-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Model class as below:

```
public class Model {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

int price;
```

}

Try to do as below:

```
                  if (dataone.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataone.size(); i++) {

                    boolean flag = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < datas.size(); j++) {
                        if (datas.get(j).getName().equals(dataone.get(i).getName())) {
                            flag = true;
                            datas.get(j).setPrice(datas.get(j).getPrice() + dataone.get(i).getPrice());
                            break;
                        } else {
                            flag = false;

                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag) {
                        datas.add(dataone.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Change your

```
 datas.get(k).setPrice(datas.get(k).getPrice() + dataone.get(j).getPrice());
```

with

```
 datas.get(k).setPrice(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(datas.get(k).getPrice()) + Integer.parseInt(dataone.get(j).getPrice())));
```

Comment: I'm not getting your point.If you want your complete Model then use ArrayList<Model > but if you want only name, you should use ArrayList<String>.

Comment: @DharmikPatel It took much time but finally I solved your problem, please replace your for loop with above edited for loop.

Comment: In your getView method of adapter class try to text for profit textview as this profit.setText(String.valueOf(datas.get(position).price));

Answer (score 0):

#### Getter & Setter with Parcelabler Object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class DeviceModel implements Parcelable {
private String mModelName;
private String mModelPrice;

public DeviceModel() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DeviceModel(String mModelName, String mModelPrice) {
    super();
    this.mModelName = mModelName;
    this.mModelPrice = mModelPrice;
}

public String getmModelName() {
    return mModelName;
}

public void setmModelName(String mModelName) {
    this.mModelName = mModelName;
}

public String getmModelPrice() {
    return mModelPrice;
}

public void setmModelPrice(String mModelPrice) {
    this.mModelPrice = mModelPrice;
}

protected DeviceModel(Parcel in) {
    mModelName = in.readString();
    mModelPrice = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mModelName);
    dest.writeString(mModelPrice);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DeviceModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DeviceModel>() {
    @Override
    public DeviceModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DeviceModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DeviceModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DeviceModel[size];
    }
  };
}
```

Use `removeDuplicate` to remove duplicates & add.

```
private void removeDuplicates(){
try{
    ArrayList<DeviceModel> mListOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<DeviceModel> mListRefined = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < mListOriginal.size(); i++){
        boolean isDuplicateFound = false;
        int mPrice = Integer.parseInt(mListOriginal.get(i).getmModelPrice());
        for(int j = 0 ;j < mListOriginal.size() ;j++){
            if(i==j){//Don't check the same index
                continue;
            }
            
            if(mListOriginal.get(i).getmModelName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(mListOriginal.get(j).getmModelName())){ //check whether they're same
                //Add Price of both - value //priceAdding
                isDuplicateFound = true;
                mPrice += Integer.parseInt(mListOriginal.get(j).getmModelPrice());//If same add price
            }   
        }
        
        if(!isDuplicateFound){//If no duplicate found, add directly to refined list
            mListRefined.add(mListOriginal.get(i));
        }else{//If duplicate found
            for(int k = 0 ; k< mListRefined.size(); k++){
                if(mListRefined.get(k).getmModelName().equalsIgnoreCase(mListOriginal.get(i).getmModelName())){ //check which it was
                    //Add price only //mListRefined.get(k).addPrice(priceAdding);
                    mListRefined.get(k).setmModelPrice(String.valueOf(mPrice));//set the price by adding
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
 }
}
```